# .htaccess and WordPress Admin Bar

Tags: htaccess

I have a built a number of WordPress sites for clients and my usual practice is to keep all the WP stuff in a /wordpress/ directory at root level. However, I don't like this directory appearing in the urls, so I simply omit it from the links and use .htaccess to reinsert it silently...

```
# If it's not a direct request for an existing file or directory,
# then add /wordpress/ at the start of every filepath unless it's there already

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !^\/wordpress\/.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /wordpress/$1 [L,NE]
```

(This is a manual edit to the .htaccess file at the root level of the site. The .htaccess file in the /wordpress/ directory implements the `/%postname%` permalink structure.)

This arrangement worked fine until the Admin Bar arrived (WordPress 3.1?). The problem I have now - on all these sites - is that the Admin Bar (on the front end for logged-in users) is only displayed if I manually reinsert "/wordpress/" into the url in the address bar of the browser.

`http://www.hlbc.org.uk/wordpress/about`   - Admin Bar visible

`http://www.hlbc.org.uk/about`   - Admin Bar **not** visible

I rather suspect that this is something to do with the [WP_Rewrite object](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Rewrite), but I haven't yet attempted to wrestle with this.

Can anyone give me some pointers to help me understand what's going on? Any help much appreciated. Thanks!

---

@Milo: Thanks. Didn't know about that hack. But for ease of upgrades I'd prefer something that didn't require messing with WP core files - and I'd still like to know why my system doesn't work!

@Sean Lee: Nice try - and useful. Spent many hours fiddling with deregistering etc and am now convinced that it's nothing to do with javascript, but rather that without `/wordpress/` in the url, I'm not regarded as logged in at all. Is this likely to be a problem with `COOKIEPATH` perhaps?

@Milo: I'll give that another look and maybe try it out on the next site I do. I was initially put off by the bit about having to edit the WP `index.php` file. But I suppose if it's outside the `\wordpress\` directory then it's not likely to be overwritten when upgrading. Are the 2 active lines of code in it guaranteed never to change in future versions?

Comment: Is there a reason you don't just set your site URL to the root of the domain under settings > general? see [giving wordpress its own directory](http://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory).

Comment: How about deregistering both the admin_bar style and script, and re-enqueue it with those under your own path?

Comment: @Bill Phelps - it doesn't "mess with core files", upgrading is seamless, as WordPress is designed to operate this way as an option. I set up all my sites like that. trying to correct this via .htaccess is far more of a hack since you can no longer use WP generated htaccess rules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK. It appears it was a cookie path problem.

I eventually solved it by adding `@define( 'ADMIN_COOKIE_PATH', '/' );` to the start of `wp-config.php` - as suggested by [AppFlak](http://www.appflak.com/blog/technical/wordpress-admin-site-error-login-php-redirects-to-wp-admin).

The vital clue came from monitoring the output of `wp_parse_auth_cookie()` under various states.

Thanks for the ideas, guys! Makes it a lot easier with extra brains on the case :)